# How to prevent Exception from within a lambda expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I am stuck in Visual Studio 2013 for a while, so I wrote a stand in for the null conditional operator implemented as follows:

```
public static TResult IfNotNull<TResult, TTarget>(this TTarget target, Func<TTarget, TResult> operation)
    where TResult : class
{
    if (target != null && operation != null)
    {
        try
        {
            return operation(target);
        } 
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        { }
    }

    return default(TResult);
}
```

I've done this to enhance the readability of code in lieu of the operator. This gets rid of hundreds of trinary operators used in class initialization code, not bad code, but difficult to read.

**The problem** is not with this function. It works well. The problem is with its usage:

```
var myValue = myEntity.Property.IfNotNull(p => p.FirstProperty.SecondaryProperty);
```

In the case that `FirstProperty` is null, Visual Studio reports the `NullReferenceException` even though I am handling it. This can be very annoying, even prohibitive if done in a long loop. I don't usually get `NullReferenceException` exceptions, but I don't really want to turn this exception warning off. The reason I am catching `NullReferenceException` (obviously the null conditional operator doesn't do this) is that I want to avoid nesting of `IfNotNull` in cases of compound property paths.

I don't want to use reflection as I want the contents of `operation` to be whatever the consumer wants it to be (e.g, methods, fields, even logical operations).

I really can't wait until we upgrade to Visual Studio 2017.

(Yes, I am aware that the null conditional operator is available in Visual Studio 2015. We are upgrading to 2017 because it is the latest version.)

**Further:** Visual Studio reports the exception as a popup window when I am debugging. This will not occur at run time or in a unit test unless you are debugging. **I have a catch block, Visual Studio should not be popping up this exception while debugging. It should just be caught.**

**Still Further:** Alright, I think I know what people are asking for. This is not a run-time issue. It is a debug issue. Visual Studio is reporting a thrown NullReferenceException from within a lambda expression that is called from within a try catch block that catches NullReferenceException. *Why should Visual Studio warn me about this, and how can I make it stop?* That is as concise as I can be.

Comment: Use C#6 (VS2015): `var myValue = myEntity?.Property?.SecondaryProperty;`

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP is not able to use that given version of VS ie(still using VS2013)

Comment: @Nkosi: I've seen it. I have commented it because 1.) OP doesn't need 2017 if he can get 2015 2.) someone else might not know this new feature even if he has 2015

Comment: @TimSchmelter granted. but possibility exists that if stuck on VS2013 they wont be able to upgrade.

Comment: I work for an enterprise and do not have an MSDN account. Stuck means stuck... for now.

Comment: @jordan+  Nkosi: If my comment would solve this issue for people who are stuck on VS2013 i'd have posted an answer instead. Can't you imagine that it might be helpful for others? Btw, very unfriendly comment Jordan to someone who has read your question and **was** willing to help

Comment: @Jordan where are you getting the exception? I created a unit test for the extension method and it passes in VS2013 with no exception. provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Nkosi, The exception is ultimately caught within `IfNotNull`. That's not the problem. The problem is that Visual Studio keeps telling me there is an exception nearly 500 times in large loops on code that I'm not even working on. Its frustrating.

Comment: @Jordan, Then this is an XY problem. Update question with the actual problem.

Comment: @Nkosi, please remove the scarlet MCVE. This is easily reproducible if you debug.

Comment: @Jordan I was debugging in the unit test when I mentioned that it was not throwing the exception.

Comment: Have you disabled "Break when thrown" for that exception in the debugger/exception options?

Comment: @PeterRitchie - I want it to break for NullReferenceExceptions when they occur in the wild. But I don't want it to break and warn when they occur in an expression that is called within a try catch block. This is a handled exception.

Comment: @jordon  when "Break when thrown" is on, the debugger breaks on all exceptions of that type thrown, regardless of whether they are caught.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, Oh! Well, "Break when thrown" is off for every exception in my Debug -> Exceptions options.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment so posting here for review.

The following unit test was done using the example provided in the OP

```
[TestMethod]
public void _TestNullCoalesceningExtension() {
    var myEntity = new MyEntity 
    {
        Property = new AnotherEntity()
    };
    var myValue = myEntity.Property.IfNotNull(p => p.FirstProperty.SecondaryProperty);
    Assert.IsNull(myValue);
}

public class MyEntity {
    public AnotherEntity Property { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherEntity {
    public YetAnotherClass FirstProperty { get; set; }
}

public class YetAnotherClass {
    public object SecondaryProperty { get; set; }
}
```

No exception was thrown either while debugging or running it to completion.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: You would have to do ^this^ to get the exception warning. If `Property` is null then it just returns default. Its if `FirstProperty` is null that I get the warning. When the exception happens within the lambda.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get the warning when I debug it as a unit test.

Comment: I get the same outcome with the update. no exception or warning.